# ssh-agent not working with git

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-agent

On a fresh install of Cygwin (used git-bash before), I can't use `ssh-agent` with `git`.

`ssh-agent` is well configured, as `ssh` command works.

```
$ ssh git@bitbucket.org
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
logged in as lenouveau.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
```

But when using `git` command, it doesn't seem to load my ssh key.

```
$ git fetch
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

`git-gui` works well.

With another terminal (ex: git-bash), it works too.

My .ssh folder :

```
$ ls -al ~/.ssh
total 38
drwx------+ 1 LeNouveau Aucun      0  3 juil. 11:39 .
drwxrwx---+ 1 Système  Système    0  3 juil. 11:37 ..
-rw-------+ 1 LeNouveau Aucun    133  3 juil. 11:39 agent.env
-rwx------+ 1 LeNouveau Aucun   1766 16 avr.  09:33 id_rsa
-rwx------+ 1 LeNouveau Aucun    402 16 avr.  09:33 id_rsa.pub
-rwx------+ 1 LeNouveau Aucun   3013 26 juin  14:34 known_hosts
```

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found my mistake : I was using my windows command `git` (from git for windows) instead of the cygwin one.

Uninstalling the Windows one and installing the cygwin one solved my problem.